# Angular 6 avoid callback hell

Tags: rxjs, angular6

Coming from AngularJS I'm struggling trying to solve the next problem. I need a function that returns an object (lets call it **A**, but this object cannot be returned till all the requests that are contained in that function are resolved. The process should be like:

1. The object **A** is downloaded from a remote server
2. Using **A**, we do operations over another object (**B**)

   1. **B** is downloaded from the server
   2. **B** is patched using some attributes from **A**
3. Using **A** and the result of **B** we do operations over a third object, **C**

   1. **C** is downloaded from the server
   2. **C** is patched using some attributes from **A** and **B**
4. After **B** and **C** are processed, the function must return **A**

I'd like to understand how to do something like this using *rxjs*, but with Angular 6 most of the examples around the internet seem to be deprecated, and the tutorials out there are not really helping me. And I cannot modify the backend to make this a bit more elegant. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following Observables:

```
const sourceA = httpClient.get(/*...*/);
const sourceB = httpClient.get(/*...*/);
const sourceC = httpClient.get(/*...*/);
```

Where `httpClient` is Angular's [HTTPClient](https://angular.io/guide/http).

The sequence of the operations you described may look as follows:

```
 const A = sourceA.pipe(
    switchMap(a => sourceB.pipe(
        map(b => {
            // do some operation using a and b.
            // Return both a and b in an array, but you can
            // also return them in an object if you wish.
            return [a,b]; 
        })
    )),
    switchMap(ab => sourceC.pipe(
        map(c => {
            // do some operations using a, b, and/or c.
            return a;
       }) 
    ))
);
```

Now you just need to subscribe to `A`:

```
A.subscribe(a => console.log(a));
```

You can read about RxJs operators [here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api).

Comment: Thanks. It's finally working. And the linked resource is very useful.

Answer (score -1):

Well, first of all, it appears to me that this function-call, as described, would be somehow expected to **block** the calling process until all of the specified events have occurred – which of course is unreasonable in JavaScript.

Therefore, first of all, I believe that your function should require, as its perhaps-only parameter, a *callback* that will be invoked when everything has finally taken place.

Now – as to "how to handle steps 1, 2, and 3 *elegantly"* ... what immediately comes to mind is the notion of a **finite-state machine (FSM)** algorithm.

Let's say that your function-call causes a new "request" to be placed on some request-table queue, and, if necessary, a timer-request (set to go off in 1 millisecond) to service that queue.  (This entry will contain, among other things, a reference to your callback.) Let's assume also that the request is given a random-string "nonce" that will serve to uniquely identify it:  this will be passed to the various external requests and must be included in their corresponding replies.

The **FSM** idea is that the request will have a ***state,*** (attribute), such as:  `DOWNLOADING_FROM_B`, `B_DOWNLOADS_COMPLETE`, `DOWNLOADING_FROM_C`, `C_REQUESTS_COMPLETE`, and so on.  Such that each and every callback that will play a part in this fully-asynchronous process will *(1)* be able to locate a request-entry by its nonce, and then *(2)* unambiguously "know what to do next," and "what new-state (if any) to assign," based solely upon examination of the entry's `state`.

For instance, when the state reaches `C_REQUESTS_COMPLETE`, it would be time to invoke the callback that you originally provided, and to delete the request-table entry.

You can easily map-out all of the "state transitions" that might occur in an arbitrarily-complex scenario *(what states can lead to what states, and what to do when they do),* whether or not you actually create a data-structure to represent that so-called "state table," although sometimes it is even-more elegant(!) when you do.  (Possibly-messy decision logic is simply pushed to a simple table-lookup.)

This is, of course, a classic algorithm that is applicable to – and, has been used in – "every programming language under the sun."  (Lots of hardware devices use it, too.)